# Delete first row in Dataframe each day for certain value only

Tags: python, pandas

Is there a way to delete the first row in a Dataframe, each day, for certain value only.  So for example:

```
2014-03-04 10:00:00   -1.0
2014-03-04 10:04:00    1.0
2014-03-04 10:42:00   -1.0

2014-03-05 09:57:00    1.0
2014-03-05 10:05:00   -1.0
2014-03-05 10:30:00    1.0
```

For each day above if 1.0 is the first value the row should be deleted.  So in the example above this would see row `2014-03-05 10:00:00` deleted.

I can't think of a way to do this without iterating through the dataframe rows using something like `for day in df.index:` which is slow to process a large dataset.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can first `groupby` by [`DatetimeIndex.year`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DatetimeIndex.year.html) and aggregate [`head`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.head.html). Then find all first indexes where value of column is `1` by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) and last [`drop`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html) them:

*This solution works nice, if datetimes are not duplicated.*

```
print (df)
                     col
2014-03-04 10:00:00 -1.0
2014-03-04 10:04:00  1.0
2014-03-04 10:42:00 -1.0
2014-03-05 09:57:00  1.0
2014-03-05 10:05:00 -1.0
2014-03-05 10:30:00  1.0

df1 = df.col.groupby(df.index.date).head(1)
print (df1)
2014-03-04 10:00:00   -1.0
2014-03-05 09:57:00    1.0
Name: col, dtype: float64

print (df1[df1 == 1].index)
DatetimeIndex(['2014-03-05 09:57:00'], dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq=None)

print (df.drop(df1[df1 == 1].index))
                     col
2014-03-04 10:00:00 -1.0
2014-03-04 10:04:00  1.0
2014-03-04 10:42:00 -1.0
2014-03-05 10:05:00 -1.0
2014-03-05 10:30:00  1.0
```

Comment: This is much better than iterating through the dataframe.  Thanks again jezrael.

Comment: Glad can help you. Nice day!

Answer (score 1):

Here is another method of creating a mask variable using `apply` method to check each group and pick up the condition of the first element, and then use the `mask` for subsetting:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df['date_time'] = pd.to_datetime(df.date_time)
df

#             date_time  value
#0  2014-03-04 10:00:00     -1
#1  2014-03-04 10:04:00      1
#2  2014-03-04 10:42:00     -1
#3  2014-03-05 09:57:00      1
#4  2014-03-05 10:05:00     -1
#5  2014-03-05 10:30:00      1

# group by the date of the column `date_time`
groups = df.groupby(df.date_time.apply(lambda dt: dt.date()))['value']

# create a mask that returns true if the first element of every group is one
mask = groups.apply(lambda g: pd.Series((np.arange(g.size) == 0) & (g == 1)))

mask
# 0    False
# 1    False
# 2    False
# 3     True
# 4    False
# 5    False
# dtype: bool


df[~mask]

#             date_time   value
#0  2014-03-04 10:00:00      -1
#1  2014-03-04 10:04:00       1
#2  2014-03-04 10:42:00      -1
#4  2014-03-05 10:05:00      -1
#5  2014-03-05 10:30:00       1
```